# Asp.net page show this site can't be reached page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When clicking the link to the page it shows the following page
[image]

whereas it works sometimes,
I tried to debug the website it seems that the request repeated till IIS failed and return
this site can't be reached page as above.

Can you help me

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because an error occurred and I return

```
return HttpNotFound();
```

Answer (score -1):

This screen will appear when you stop Debugging. You want to debugg once more or
right click on the page you want to see in browser and select view in browser option.

Comment: why do you think this is the case?

Comment: without debugging it shows as above and sometimes it shows the page